# How to fix the values submitted in the form not reflecting to the http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ i.e my local host

Tags: php, html

I have a form(Insert new post here) where I am trying to post the entered values to the localhost.
I couldn't see my values entered in my local host.
I am getting the following error:
"Error in response to storage.get: Syntax Error: Unexpected token at Object.callback".
To resolve it I have cleared the browser cache and application cache but cannot resolve.

I have added the following debug int the PHP code but this is not reflecting:

```
echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted')</script>";
```

PHP Code:

```
 <?php  
   if(isset($POST['insert_post'])){
        //getting the text data from fields
        $product_title = $_POST['product_title'];
        $product_cat = $_POST['product_cat'];
        $product_brand = $_POST['product_brand'];
        $product_price = $_POST['product_price'];
        $product_desc = $_POST['product_desc'];
        $product_keywords = $_POST['product_keywords'];
        //getting the image from the fields
        $product_image = $_FILES['product_image']['name'];
        $product_image_tmp = $_FILES['product_image']['tmp_name'];
        //uploading an image  
         move_uploaded_file
        ($product_image_tmp,"product_images/$product_image");
         echo $insert_product="insert into products   
         (product_cat,
          product_brand,       
          product_title,
          product_price,
          product_desc,
          product_image,
          product_keywords)
        values      
        (
        '$product_cat',
        '$product_brand',
        '$product_title',
        '$product_price',
        '$product_desc',
        '$product_image',
        '$product_keywords'
        )";
        $insert_pro = mysqli_query($con,$insert_product);
        if($insert_pro){
        echo "<script>alert('Product has been inserted')</script>";  
        echo "<script>window('insert_product.php','_self')</script>";}
   }
?>
```

I expect to get an alert as "Product has been inserted" but at present I am not getting it.
Once I get it the inserted data will be saved to the local host.[entered_value_in_the_form]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the php function executed in an async call? If so, you shouldn't echo the $insert_product variable, otherwise, you may get syntax errors.

Comment: I have added echo $insert_product for debugging purpose only so as to get the values at least in the web page where we are inserting the values to the form as a user.But,I am not getting that too.